# Is the Healthcare Finder API broken?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

Going to any of the API version pages, like...

https://finder.healthcare.gov/services/version_2_0

And attempting to download the schema results in an error message, like...

> Access Denied
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   "http://finder.healthcare.gov/api/finder_api_v2.0.xsd" on this server.
>   Reference #18.9f6a1db8.1403276369.429a99a1

I did not see any messaging that the API is broken or outdated, just that it's going to be changed.  And I did not see any way to apply for schema access or report a bug on the site.

Trying to use the API to create a health insurance information site, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was going to give a link to the 'Give Feedback' link on the bottom of their page, but that gives a 404 with "Sorry, we can't find that page
on HealthCare.gov
We've recently reorganized our site, and that may explain it.
It's also possible that you typed the address incorrectly."  (and it wasn't my typing).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that - there was a firewall rule blocking download of that file. We have fixed this and the link to the schema document should now be working.

Comment: Jon - I am still getting an access denied error.

Comment: @Jon : I can confifm that access is still denied.

Comment: Yes, still broken - same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to make any API calls but here is the XSD on Github: https://github.com/faraazkhan/finder-api-cgi/blob/master/doc/finder_xsd/finder_api_v2.0.xsd

Of course that doesn't mean the file linked to above is up to date or accurate or that the API servers are running either.

If you're looking to create a "health information site," surely some of the data sets at https://data.healthcare.gov/ will be of interest to you. [Here](http://socialhealthinsights.com/2013/10/healthcare-gov-open-data/) is a blog post I wrote the day that data hit the 'net about what's in there and some visualizations off of the data.

Comment: Also check out some of the data in https://github.com/faraazkhan/finder-api-cgi/tree/master/data/db even though it's 9 months old.